# How to send and receive message using xmpp in php

Tags: php, xmpp, xmpphp

```
include("xmpp.php");
$conn = new XMPP(
   'talk.google.com',
   5222,
   'username',
   'password',
   'xmpphp',
   'gmail.com',
);
//$conn->use_encryption = false; // Optional
$conn->connect();
$conn->processUntil('session_start');
$conn->message('someguy@someserver.net', 'This is a test message!');
$conn->disconnect();
```

I am trying to send messages using this code but not able to send message.
I also have to receive messages also.
I have wamp server setup

Answer (score 0):

Remove last comma `,` and try like this.

```
$conn = new XMPP(
'talk.google.com',
5222,
'username',
'password',
'xmpphp',
'gmail.com'
);
```

Comment: i only have to enter my user name and password of google acc. just to send message?

Comment: after entering username and password and mail id i got this error parse error unexpected t string on line 3